# Build CMS in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am an asp.net (C#) developer and have been developing CMS systems for quite a while and now I need to develop a CMS in SharePoint.

Can you please suggest me steps, methods or tutorials or step by step procedures (free links) for developing a CMS in SharePoint?

Comment: You don't have to make 2 exactly same questions. You can modify existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has asked a similar question and got an excellent response [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/1482684f-a973-45bb-860f-659b4987aab8).